# Python 3- "local variable referenced before assignment" with imported code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a school assignment that requires me to use the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re
jfif = re.compile(b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0..JFIF\x00',
              flags = re.DOTALL)
exif = re.compile(b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1..EXIF\x00',
              flags = re.DOTALL)
spiff = re.compile(b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe8..SPIFF\x00',
              flags = re.DOTALL)

f = open('manson.dd', 'rb')
sector = f.read(512)

count = 0

while len(sector) != 0:
     if jfif.match(sector):
         count += 1
         print('found JFIF at offset {:X}, sector {}'.format(
             f.tell()-512, (f.tell()  - 512) // 512))

     elif exif.match(sector):
         count += 1
         print('found EXIF at offset {:X}, sector {}'.format(
             f.tell()-512, (f.tell()  - 512) // 512))

     elif pdf.match(sector):
         pdfCount += 1
         print('found PDF at offset {:X}, sector {}'.format(
             f.tell()-512, (f.tell()  - 512) // 512))
     sector = f.read(512)

print("Found", count, "JPEG Files")
```

**The assignment requires me to make a new script that finds GIF files and imports the actual search function into a script that prompts for the file and prints the result**

**This is what I have so far**

*Main Script*

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import search

fileName = input("Enter the file you would like to search: ")
f = open(fileName, 'rb')
sector = f.read(512)

search.crawl()

print("Found", count, "GIF Files")
```

*Imported Code*

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

gif = re.compile(b'\x47\x49\x46\x38..GIF\x61',
              flags = re.DOTALL)
def crawl():
    count = 0
    while len(sector) != 0:
             if gif.match(sector):
                 count += 1
                 print('found GIF at offset {:X}, sector {}'.format(
                     f.tell()-512, (f.tell()  - 512) // 512))
                 sector = f.read(512)
```

When I run the main script, I am told that "the local variable 'sector' is referenced before assignment'. I haven't the slightest idea how to rectify this.

Comment: put a `sector = f.read(512)` line before your while loop in `crawl` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `def crawl()`, use `def crawl(sector)`.
And then instead of calling `search.crawl()`, call `search.crawl(sector)`.

Also, you will encounter a similar error with `count`.
So you should modify `search.crawl(sector)` to return `count` and then when you call search.crawl(sector) in main(), assign to variable count.

In `main`:

```
count = search.crawl(sector)
```

In `search`:

```
def crawl(sector):
    count = 0
    while len(sector) != 0:
             if gif.match(sector):
                 count += 1
                 print('found GIF at offset {:X}, sector {}'.format(
                     f.tell()-512, (f.tell()  - 512) // 512))
                 sector = f.read(512) 
    return count
```

The reason for this is because when you import the module `search`, it has no notion of the `sector` variable. The only way for `main`'s `sector` to be sent into `search.crawl()` is for it to be passed in as a function parameter a la `search.crawl(sector)`.

Comment: I understand why that should work, but when I made those changes, instead of the error coming up, it just hangs until I kill it. It's like the while loop is going infinitely for some reason. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`sector` variable isn't global, you can pass it to crawl function

```
def crawl(sector):
```

and then:

```
search.crawl(sector)
```